# WCF - VS2005 to VS2008 Sln Conversion Problem

Tags: wcf, projects-and-solutions

I have converted a VS2005 solution to VS2008 solution.

I am trying to Add a Service Reference to a project in the solution but not finding the desired option in the Right click -> Popup Menu.

I am not trying to add a Web Reference. I am trying to add a Service Reference. I am working with a WCF Client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the Project (Project-->Properties) is set to Target Framework ".NET Framework 3.0" or ".NET Framework 3.5".

Maybe it isn´t changed during conversion from VS 2005 to VS 2008

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the "Add Web Reference" option, like in VS2005?

You need to right-click your project, select "Add Service Reference", then click the "Advanced" button in the bottom-left of the popup window, and then click the "Add Web Reference" button in the bottom-left of the next popup window.

Comment: I am not trying to add a Web Reference. I am trying to add a Service Reference. I am working with WCF.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the project must be either a C# or VB project in order for the Add Service Reference option to be available.  If you add a CLR-enabled C++ project, you'll have access to the Add Web Reference option, but not the Add Service Reference option.  If the C++ project is not CLR-enabled, then neither of these options are available.  Can you confirm what type of project you're using?